# Angular Form has no controls in the component

Tags: angular, angular-forms

My form has no controls when accessing in the component:

[image]

Here is the form (note the "name" attributes):

```
<form #finaliseForm="ngForm"
          fxLayout="column"
          fxFlex>
        <div fxLayout="row">
            <div fxLayout="column"
                 fxFlex="50"
                 class="cb-margin-right-2x">
                <cb-display-value-new label="Lot"
                                      [value]="currentMappedItem.lotDescription">
                </cb-display-value-new>
                <cb-display-value-new label="Design Scheme"
                                      [value]="currentMappedItem.revisionNumber">
                </cb-display-value-new>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column"
                 fxFlex="50">
                <cb-display-value-new label="Concept M2"
                                      [value]="currentMappedItem.amenities?.floorArea">
                </cb-display-value-new>
                <cb-display-value-new label="Job #"
                                      [value]="currentMappedItem.jobNumber">
                </cb-display-value-new>
            </div>
        </div>
        <mat-divider class="cb-margin-bottom-2x"></mat-divider>
        <div fxFlex
             fxLayout="row">
            <div fxLayout="column"
                 fxFlex
                 class="cb-margin-right-2x">
                <cb-display-value-new label="Previous Pricing Revision"
                                      *ngIf="previousMappedItem !== undefined"
                                      [value]="previousMappedItem?.revisionNumber">
                </cb-display-value-new>
                <cb-display-value-new label="Margin %"
                                      *ngIf="previousMappedItem !== undefined"
                                      [value]="previousMappedItem?.margin">
                </cb-display-value-new>
                <cb-currency *ngIf="previousMappedItem !== undefined"
                             label="Land Price"
                             [required]="!canEditLandPrice"
                             [inclGst]="true"
                             [readonly]="!canEditLandPrice"
                             name="designAndLandLotDeposit"
                             [(ngModel)]="previousMappedItem.landPrice">
                </cb-currency>
                <cb-currency *ngIf="previousMappedItem !== undefined"
                             label="Build Cost"
                             [inclGst]="true"
                             [readonly]="true"
                             name="buildCost"
                             [(ngModel)]="previousMappedItem.buildCost">
                </cb-currency>
                <cb-currency *ngIf="previousMappedItem !== undefined"
                             label="Build Price"
                             [inclGst]="true"
                             [readonly]="true"
                             name="buildPrice"
                             [(ngModel)]="previousMappedItem.buildPrice">
                </cb-currency>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column"
                 fxFlex>
                <cb-display-value-new label="Current Pricing Revision"
                                      [value]="currentMappedItem.revisionNumber">
                </cb-display-value-new>
                <cb-input name="targetWorkHours"
                          label="Margin %"
                          [required]="true"
                          [(ngModel)]="currentMappedItem.margin">
                </cb-input>
                <cb-currency name="landPrice"
                             label="Land Price"
                             [required]="true"
                             [readonly]="!canEditLandPrice"
                             [(ngModel)]="currentMappedItem.landPrice">
                </cb-currency>
                <cb-currency name="buildCost"
                             label="Build Cost"
                             [required]="true"
                             [readonly]="!canEditLandPrice"
                             [(ngModel)]="currentMappedItem.buildCost">
                </cb-currency>
                <cb-currency name="buildPrice"
                             label="Build Price"
                             [required]="true"
                             [(ngModel)]="currentMappedItem.buildPrice">
                </cb-currency>
                <cb-currency name="buildPrice"
                             label="Build Price"
                             [required]="true"
                             [inclGst]="true"
                             [readonly]="true"
                             [(ngModel)]="currentMappedItem.buildPrice">
                </cb-currency>
            </div>
        </div>
        <mat-divider class="cb-margin-bottom"></mat-divider>
        <div fxLayout="column"
             class="cb-margin"
             fxFlex>
            <cb-text-area label="Comments and Assumptions"
                          [(ngModel)]="currentMappedItem.qsNotes"
                          name="qsNotes"
                          [maxlength]="1024">
            </cb-text-area>
            <cb-checkbox name="isEstimatedPrice"
                         label="Price is an Estimate"
                         [(ngModel)]="currentMappedItem.isEstimatedPrice">
            </cb-checkbox>
            <cb-datepicker name="pricingExpiryDate"
                           [(ngModel)]="currentMappedItem.pricingExpiryDate"
                           [minDate]="minDate"
                           pickerType="calendar"
                           label="Price Expiry Date">
            </cb-datepicker>
        </div>
        <footer fxLayout="row"
                fxLayoutAlign="end center"
                class="cb-margin-top-2x">
            <cb-button *ngIf="canSubmitForReview$ | async"
                       [clickLimit]="1"
                       [disabled]="isSaveDisabled$ | async"
                       class="cb-margin-right"
                       (clicked)="submitForReview()">
                Submit for Review
            </cb-button>
            <cb-button *ngIf="canFinalise$ | async"
                       [clickLimit]="1"
                       [disabled]="isSaveDisabled$ | async"
                       class="cb-margin-right"
                       (clicked)="finaliseClicked()">
                Finalise
            </cb-button>
            <cb-button (clicked)="cancel()"
                       color="">
                Cancel
            </cb-button>
        </footer>
    </form>
```

How I access the form:

```
@ViewChild(NgForm, { static: true }) public finaliseForm;
```

Note I have tried this too:

```
@ViewChild('finaliseForm', { static: true }) public finaliseForm: NgForm;
```

I have also tried without `static`.

Why are the controls missing from the form in the component?

**EDIT: Must be a timing thing. I have done this as a workaround which works (shouldn't have to):**

```
public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (Object.keys(this.finaliseForm.controls).length > 0 && !this._isFormInitialised) {
        this.isSaveDisabled$ = this.finaliseForm.valueChanges.pipe(
            map(_ => {
                const isQSTeam = this.currentUser?.isQSTeam();
                const pristine = this.finaliseForm?.pristine;
                const invalid = this.finaliseForm?.invalid;
                const assignedToCurrentUser = this.currentMappedItem.assignedToUserId === this.currentUser?.guid;
                const reviewIsGood = (!this.currentMappedItem.reviewRequired ||
                    this.currentMappedItem.reviewerId === this.currentUser?.guid);
                return !(isQSTeam &&
                    !pristine &&
                    !invalid &&
                    assignedToCurrentUser &&
                reviewIsGood);
            }));
        this._isFormInitialised = true;
        this.isSaveDisabled$.subscribe(console.log);
    }
}
```

EDIT: the `cb-display-value-new` template:

```
<label class="label">{{label}}</label>
<div fxLayout="row"
     fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <span cbEllipsis="applyEllipsis"
          [ngClass]="!this.applyEllipsis ? 'content' : 'truncate-content'"
          class="mat-body-1"
          *ngIf="!contentRef?.innerHTML?.trim()">{{value | cbDasher}}</span>
    <button *ngIf="showBtn && btnCondition !== false"
            mat-icon-button
            (click)="handleClick($event)"
            class="cb-grey">
        <mat-icon>{{btnIcon != null ? btnIcon : 'pageview'}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
<div cbEllipsis="applyEllipsis"
     #contentRef
     [ngClass]="!this.applyEllipsis ? 'content' : 'truncate-content'">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A template driven form registers a form control only when it encounter "name" attribute along with "ngModel" directive attached to input element.

Although you happen to have them on your component selector "cb-display-value-new", can you cross check if you have same values with the input element inside the template of "cb-display-value-new" component?

Although the problem is not with the way you have declared and using `ViewChild` just one thing about `ViewChild` with `static: true` property - You use static = true only when you want to access variable before the change detection have taken place i.e. in `ngOnInit` hook. More learning on this - https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration#what-does-this-flag-mean-and-why-is-it-necessary